# numpy: aggregate 4D array by groups

Tags: numpy, pandas, python-itertools

I have a numpy array with shape [t, z, x, y]  epresenting an hourly time series of three-D data.  The axes of the array are time, vertical coordinate, horizontal coordinate 1, horizontal coordinate 2.  There is also a t-element list of hourly datetime.datetime timestamps.

I want to calculate the daily mid-day means for each day.  This will be an [nday, Z, X, Y] array.

I'm trying to find a pythonic way to do this.  I've written something with a bunch of for loops that works but seems slow, inflexible, and verbose.

It appears to me that Pandas is not a solution for me because my time series data are three-dimensional.  I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

I've come up with this, using itertools, to find mid-day timestamps and group them by date, and now I'm coming up short trying to apply imap to find the means.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# create 72 hours of pseudo-data with 3 vertical levels and a 4 by 4
# horizontal grid.
data = np.zeros((72, 3, 4, 4))
t = pd.date_range(datetime(2008,7,1), freq='1H', periods=72)
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[i,...] = i

# find the timestamps that are "midday" in North America.  We'll
# define midday as between 15:00 and 23:00 UTC, which is 10:00 EST to
# 15:00 PST.
def is_midday(this_t):
    return ((this_t.hour >= 15) and (this_t.hour <= 23))

# group the midday timestamps by date
for dt, grp in itertools.groupby(itertools.ifilter(is_midday, t),
                                 key=lambda x: x.date()):
    print 'date ' + str(dt)
    for g in grp:
        print g

# find means of mid-day data by date 
data_list = np.split(data, data.shape[0])
grps = itertools.groupby(itertools.ifilter(is_midday, t),
                         key=lambda x: x.date())
# how to apply itertools.imap (or something else) to data_list and
# grps?  Or somehow split data along axis 0 according to grps?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shove pretty much any object into a pandas structure. Normally not recommended, but in this case it might work for you.

Create a Series indexed by time, with each element a 3-d numpy array

```
In [117]: s = Series([data[i] for i in range(data.shape[0])],index=t)

In [118]: s
Out[118]: 
2008-07-01 00:00:00    [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], ...
2008-07-01 01:00:00    [[[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], ...
2008-07-01 02:00:00    [[[2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0], ...
2008-07-01 03:00:00    [[[3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], ...
2008-07-01 04:00:00    [[[4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0], [4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0], ...
2008-07-01 05:00:00    [[[5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0], ...
2008-07-01 06:00:00    [[[6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0], [6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0], ...
2008-07-01 07:00:00    [[[7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0], [7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0], ...
2008-07-01 08:00:00    [[[8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0], [8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0], ...
2008-07-01 09:00:00    [[[9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0], [9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0], ...
2008-07-01 10:00:00    [[[10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0], [10.0, 10.0, 10.0,...
2008-07-01 11:00:00    [[[11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0], [11.0, 11.0, 11.0,...
2008-07-01 12:00:00    [[[12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0], [12.0, 12.0, 12.0,...
2008-07-01 13:00:00    [[[13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0], [13.0, 13.0, 13.0,...
2008-07-01 14:00:00    [[[14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0], [14.0, 14.0, 14.0,...
...
2008-07-03 09:00:00    [[[57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0], [57.0, 57.0, 57.0,...
2008-07-03 10:00:00    [[[58.0, 58.0, 58.0, 58.0], [58.0, 58.0, 58.0,...
2008-07-03 11:00:00    [[[59.0, 59.0, 59.0, 59.0], [59.0, 59.0, 59.0,...
2008-07-03 12:00:00    [[[60.0, 60.0, 60.0, 60.0], [60.0, 60.0, 60.0,...
2008-07-03 13:00:00    [[[61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0], [61.0, 61.0, 61.0,...
2008-07-03 14:00:00    [[[62.0, 62.0, 62.0, 62.0], [62.0, 62.0, 62.0,...
2008-07-03 15:00:00    [[[63.0, 63.0, 63.0, 63.0], [63.0, 63.0, 63.0,...
2008-07-03 16:00:00    [[[64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0], [64.0, 64.0, 64.0,...
2008-07-03 17:00:00    [[[65.0, 65.0, 65.0, 65.0], [65.0, 65.0, 65.0,...
2008-07-03 18:00:00    [[[66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0], [66.0, 66.0, 66.0,...
2008-07-03 19:00:00    [[[67.0, 67.0, 67.0, 67.0], [67.0, 67.0, 67.0,...
2008-07-03 20:00:00    [[[68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0], [68.0, 68.0, 68.0,...
2008-07-03 21:00:00    [[[69.0, 69.0, 69.0, 69.0], [69.0, 69.0, 69.0,...
2008-07-03 22:00:00    [[[70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0], [70.0, 70.0, 70.0,...
2008-07-03 23:00:00    [[[71.0, 71.0, 71.0, 71.0], [71.0, 71.0, 71.0,...
Freq: H, Length: 72
```

Define your aggregating function. You need to access the values which returns the inside object; `concatenating` coerces back to an actual numpy array, then aggregate (mean in this case)

```
In [119]: def f(g,grp):
   .....:     return np.concatenate(grp.values).mean()
   .....:
```

Since not sure what your end output should look like, just create a time-based grouper manually (this is essentially a resample), but doesn't do anything with the final results (its just a list of the aggregated values)

```
In [121]: [ f(g,grp) for g, grp in s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')) ]
Out[121]: [11.5, 35.5, 59.5]
```

You can get reasonable fancy here and say return a pandas object (and potentially `concat` them).